# Citation of a reference in a specific format

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I am looking for references and their citation as below. However, I was not able to understand the different articles or question-answers on similar problem. Can one help me to make it in simple and with minimum commands?

---

**Introduction:**

A well-known theorem of Burnside (see [Bur1904]) says that a group whose order is divisible by only two primes is solvable. .......

**References:**

[BUR09] Burnside, W. (1904), On Groups of Order paqb, Proc. London Math. Soc., Volume s2-1, Issue 1 (1904), 388–392.

---

So here, I am putting the references with indexing them by Authors short name and year. And, I am citing them in same way. How to do this?

Comment: Looks like an alphabetic style. So you should be able to start, e.g., with `\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}` (or maybe `ext-alphabetic` instead of `alphabetic` or another alphabetic style). See the manuals for more information about configuration options.

Comment: It seems weird to have `[Bur1904]` in the body of the document but `[BUR09]` in the formatted bibliographic entry. Should the latter maybe be `[Bur1904]`, or maybe `[Bur04]`?

Comment: Off-topic: I believe it's advisable to replace `paqb` in the `title` field with `$p^{\alpha}q^{\beta}$`.

Answer (score 1):

If you employ BibTeX, the `alpha` bibliography style may be of interest to you. Assuming the bibliographic entry is of type `@article`, the `alpha` style produces the following output.

[image]

Observe that the formatted bibliographic entry deviates slightly from what the OP says is desired. (a) given names aren't abbreviated , (b) the `year` field is stated only once, (c) the three-letter abbreviation is "Bur", not "BUR", (d) the year is truncate to the final two digits (here: `04`), and (e) the volume and issue information isn't prefixed by the strings "volume" and "issue", respectively.

If the output of the `alpha` bibliography style doesn't meet your formatting needs, I suggest you familiarize yourself with the [custom-bib](https://ctan.org/pkg/custom-bib) package and its `makebst` utility. This utility lets you create highly bespoke bibliography style by answering a series of multiple-choice questions. Type `pdflatex makebst` at a command prompt to get started.

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@article{burnside:1904,
  author  = "William S. Burnside",
  title   = "On groups of order $p^{\alpha}q^{\beta}$",
  year    = 1904,
  journal = "Proceedings of The London Mathematical Society",
  volume  = "s2-1",
  number  = 1,
  pages   = "388-392",
}
  
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{cite} % or some other suitable citation management package
\bibliographystyle{alpha}

\begin{document}

\noindent
A well known theorem of Burnside (see \cite{burnside:1904}) says that \dots

\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```